# JetBrains DataGrip: Services window holding scroll position between executions

Tags: datagrip

I could see this being a feature in many instances, but has thrown us off a few times. I have 1 computer that does this and one doesnt, so hoping its a setting that I am missing. Once you execute a query in Datagrip and scroll down in the Services window. Then you run a query with less rows, the Services window will remain scrolled down making it look like less rows returned.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pagination section in the editor output showing the total amount of records. The pagination number can be increased in **File | Settings | Database | Data Editor and Viewer**. In case of significant amounts, you may distinguish the result sets by activating **Open results in new tab** option in **File | Settings | Database | Query Execution**

If using a single result set window for all query outputs, it should remember the row position of a table. When querying it again, it'll show the same position unless fewer records are returned in the result set - it's focusing on the last row, so you need to scroll way up.

Comment: Ya, I have pagination increased.  That second part if the functionality I am referring to and what I was hoping I could control with a setting. 

I should also note, that for some reason 1 computer doesn't hold the scroll position while the other does.